# Named Semaphore just not working

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore, shared-memory

we had an exam today and we had  a task to implement a "train-handler".

There are 7 trains represented by one process each. Each train arrives after a couple of seconds, checks if 1 of our 3 traintracks is available. If not, wait...
If track is free, enter it and lock it.
Stay for at the train station for a few seconds, leave and unlock it.

Me and a few friends are trying to make our program run but we just can't get it done. It seems to be the problem that our shared memory is not synchronized properly (semaphore). Using a mac, so I have to use named semaphores.

compiled with: "gcc -Wall -Werror -std=gnu99 -lpthread process_trains.c -o test"

CODE:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


sem_t *sem;
int *shm_ptr;



int *initShm (int size) {
    int shm_fd = 0;

    if((shm_fd = shm_open("/shm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)) == -1) {
        perror("Error creating shared memory segment!");
    }

    if ((ftruncate(shm_fd, size)) == -1) {
        perror("Error sizing shared memory segment!");
    }

    return (int*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
}


int trainAboutToArrive(int arrive, int stay, int Y){

    int Z=0;

    //Zug kommt in "arrive" Sekunden an
    sleep(arrive);

    while (shm_ptr[Z]!=0) {
        Z++;
        if(Z==3){
            Z=0;
        }
    }

    sem_wait(sem);
    shm_ptr[Z]=1;
    sem_post(sem);

    printf("Zug %d ist auf Gleis %d eingefahren\n", Y, 1+Z);

    //Zug hat einen Aufenthalt von "stay" Sekunden 
    sleep(stay);

    sem_wait(sem);
    shm_ptr[Z]=0;
    sem_post(sem);

    sem_close(sem);

    printf("Zug %d verlässt Gleis %d\n", Y, 1+Z);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    shm_unlink("shm");

    int i=0, tracks=3, trains=7, status;
    int arrival[]={0,0,3,2,5,4,2};
    int stay[]={2,3,7,2,1,4,3};

    off_t size = sizeof(int)*tracks;
    shm_ptr = initShm(size);

    if((sem = sem_open("/semap",O_CREAT,0644,1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("client sem_open");
    }

    for (i=0; i < tracks; i++) {
        shm_ptr[i]= 0;
    }

    pid_t pids[trains];

    for (i = 0; i < trains; i++) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if(pids[i] == -1) {
            perror("Error creating train-process!!");
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
            trainAboutToArrive(arrival[i], stay[i], 1+i);
            exit(0);
        }else if (pids[i] > 0) {

        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < trains; i++){
        waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0);
    }
    shm_unlink("shm");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to compile it at least? `sem_t *sem;` should clearly be a global.

Comment: Yeah compiles fine. And had it global before. just changed this couple of minutes ago. Wasn't working when sem-pointer was global either. More than one train enters the track...

Comment: So put the actual code here.

Comment: Why do you link against `lpthread` (in the wrong order though...) when you use `fork()`?

Comment: It doesn't compile without `-lrt` on my machine: `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=gnu99 -lrt app.c -o test`

Comment: -lpthread on OSX -lrt I'd use on Linux. Am I right? But EOF is right. don't need this here. Semaphores still dont work :D

Comment: The man page for shm_open(3) says "name  of  the form  /somename" and "shm" is not a name on that form, does it work if you pass "/shm" instead?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca To your first issue: what's the difference between an int-array and an int-pointer treating-wise? :D I believe there is none, is there? Issue 2: I don't nullify the pointer, I'm saving a "zero" at the adress the pointer points to, meaning that there's no train on that track.

Comment: @Vatine good idea! not changing a thing though :D

Answer (score 0):

Link with -pthread!!!! man page of all used semaphore functions tells us >.<

Thanks for everyones help!!

And for everyone who's interested, this is my code now. I improved a lot of things I didn't have time for in the exam. This runs perfectly and in my "beginners-eyes" this is not improvable by using the given functions (semaphores, shared mem...). If it is, I'd be grateful for tips & tricks ;)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int *shm_ptr;

int *initShm (off_t size) {

    int shm_fd = 0;

    if((shm_fd = shm_open("/shm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)) == -1) {
        perror("Error creating shared memory segment!");
    }

    if ((ftruncate(shm_fd, size)) == -1) {
        perror("Error sizing shared memory segment!");
    }

    return (int*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
}

void initSem(sem_t **plats) {

    if((plats[0] = sem_open("/one",O_CREAT,0644,1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("client sem_open");
    }
    if((plats[1] = sem_open("/two",O_CREAT,0644,1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("client sem_open");
    }
    if((plats[2] = sem_open("/three",O_CREAT,0644,1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("client sem_open");
    }
}


int trainAboutToArrive(int arrive, int stay, int train, sem_t **plats){

    srand(getpid());
    int platform = rand()%3;

    sleep(arrive);

    while (3) {
        sem_wait(plats[platform]);
        if(shm_ptr[platform]==0){
            shm_ptr[platform]=1;
            break;
        }
        sem_post(plats[platform]);

        platform = rand() % 3;
    }

    printf("Train %d enters platform %d\n", train, 1+platform);

    sleep(stay);

    shm_ptr[platform]=0;

    printf("Train %d leaves platform %d\n", train, 1+platform);

    sem_post(plats[platform]);
    sem_close(plats[platform]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    shm_unlink("/shm");
    sem_unlink("/one");
    sem_unlink("/two");
    sem_unlink("/three");

    int i=0, tracks=3, trains=7, status;
    int arrival[]={0,0,3,2,5,4,2};
    int stay[]={2,3,7,2,1,4,3};
    sem_t *plats[3];

    off_t size = sizeof(int)*tracks;
    shm_ptr = initShm(size);
    initSem(plats);

    for (i=0; i < tracks; i++) {
        shm_ptr[i]= 0;
    }

    pid_t pids[trains];

    for (i = 0; i < trains; i++) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if(pids[i] == -1) {
            perror("Error creating train-process!!");
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
            trainAboutToArrive(arrival[i], stay[i], 1+i, plats);
            exit(0);
        }else if (pids[i] > 0) {

        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < trains; i++){
        waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0);
    }

    shm_unlink("/shm");
    sem_unlink("/one");
    sem_unlink("/two");
    sem_unlink("/three");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```